# Netsuite Rest API Create Non-inventory Item for Sale

Tags: api, rest, netsuite, suitescript

I try to create a Non-Inventory Sale item with the NetSuite API.
Here is my request :
Method : **POST**
Endpoint: `/services/rest/record/v1/nonInventorySaleItem`
Payload:

```
{
    "itemId": "Test Item",
    "IncomeAccount": {
        "id": "1315"
    },
    "deterredRevenueAccount": {
        "id": "1343"
    },
    "itemType": {
        "refName": "NonInvtPart"
    },
    "location": {
        "id": "46"
    },
    "taxSchedule": {"id": "1"}
}
```

It keeps returning 400 HTTP Error and the message :

`Error while accessing a resource. Please enter value(s) for: Tax Schedule.`

I tried to work around with a custom entity field and a UserEventScript SuiteScript to update taxSchedule before submit without success.

Comment: Have you tried defaulting tax schedules or including tax schedules to your API Post Request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with NetSuite support staff and they basically said that the feature isn't supported. If you want you can create a RESTlet and recreate the functionality by accepting the parameters that you want and creating the item that way. Something roughly like this:

```js
define(['N/record'], function(record) {
    function post(context) {
        if (context.request.method !== 'POST') {
            throw {
                status: 405,
                message: 'Invalid HTTP method',
            };
        }
        
        // Parse the request body
        var requestBody = JSON.parse(context.request.body);
        
        // Create the inventory item record
        var itemRecord = record.create({
            type: record.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM,
            isDynamic: true,
        });
        
        // Set the item name, tax schedule, asset account, and cogs account
        itemRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'itemid',
            value: requestBody.name,
        });
        itemRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'taxschedule',
            value: requestBody.taxSchedule,
        });
        itemRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'assetaccount',
            value: requestBody.assetAccount,
        });
        itemRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'cogsaccount',
            value: requestBody.cogsAccount,
        });
        
        // Save the inventory item record
        var itemId = itemRecord.save({
            enableSourcing: true,
            ignoreMandatoryFields: true,
        });
        
        // Return the new inventory item ID
        return {
            id: itemId,
        };
    }
    
    return {
        post: post,
    };
});
```

Obviously also include any other fields that you want, but I found that the Tax Schedule, COGS account, and asset accounts were all required.